# How to replace actions with html icon on backpackforlaravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have created this app with `backpack for laravel` where the table created by using `backpack:build`
I need to replace the word actions with an icon from `line-awesome` for example **toolbox**

```
<i class="las la-toolbox"></i>
```

I tried to add the HTML on the language file
`resources/lang/vendor/backpack/en/crud.php` but it's not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Backpack 4.0 or 4.1, you can change the default buttons any way you see fit by [publishing the view file](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#publish-a-column-field-filter-button-and-modify-it), and making changes to the published file. If Backpack sees a file with the same name & path inside your project, it'll use that one instead of the one in the package.

For example:

- if this file exists: `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php`
- then Backpack will load that one, instead of the normal `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php`

For reference, you can find all default Backpack buttons [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/tree/master/src/resources/views/crud/buttons), in the Backpack/CRUD package. Overwriting one is just a matter of creating a file with the same name in the directory I mentioned above.

You can publish a blade file even easier by using this command:

```sh
php artisan backpack:publish crud/buttons/delete
```

Then make any changes you want to it, like removing the text to only leave the icon.

---

In Backpack 4.2 it is possible that an easier solution will be implemented for this particular need. See [this PR](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/3320) for more information. Backpack 4.2 will be released in spring 2021.